# neo4j: how to construct valid query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Conditions:

- User Emil knows Dan and Peter.
- Emil adds 1 star to video "about cats"
- Dan adds 5 stars to video "cool film" and 3 stars to video "about cats"
- Peter adds 1 star to video "cool film" and 3 stars to video "funny video"

Problem:

*Emil needs to know all videos starred by other users he knows, plus users who starred it. But, he not interested in videos he already starred.
Also, he need to get videos sorted by total rating.*

In our case output should be:

> 1) "cool film", 6 stars, starred by Dan and Peter
>
> 2) "funny video", 3 stars, starred by Peter

**Question: how query could look like?**
Thank you.

---

Query to fill database:

```
CREATE
    (emil:User { name: "Emil" }),
    (dan:User { name: "Dan" }),
    (peter:User { name: "Peter" }),
    (emil)-[:KNOWS]->(dan),
    (emil)-[:KNOWS]->(peter),
    (cool:Video { title: "cool film" }),
    (funny:Video { title: "funny video" }),
    (cats:Video { title: "about cats" }),
    (emil)-[:RATE { score: 1 }]->(cats),
    (dan)-[:RATE { score: 5 }]->(cool),
    (dan)-[:RATE { score: 3 }]->(cats),
    (peter)-[:RATE { score: 1 }]->(cool),
    (peter)-[:RATE { score: 3 }]->(funny)
```

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UofJB.png)

Comment: Have you attempted the query yourself yet? Sometimes it helps to give it a try and see how far you can get.

Comment: My longest run is **MATCH (source:User)-[:KNOWS]->(users)-[r:RATE]->(videos) where source.name = 'Emil' and NOT (source)-[:RATE]->(videos) return  videos.title, sum(r.score) as score order by score desc**. Looks almost close, but don't know how to aggregate user information into query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempted query is pretty much spot on!

The only thing missing is including the users who rated each movie. A simple `COLLECT(users)` should do the trick.

```
MATCH (source:User)-[:KNOWS]->(users)-[r:RATE]->(videos) 
where source.name = 'Emil' and NOT (source)-[:RATE]->(videos) 
return videos.title, sum(r.score) as score, COLLECT(users) as starredBy
order by score desc
```

Comment: MATCH (source:User)-[:KNOWS]->(users)-[r:RATE]->(videos) where source.name = 'Emil' and NOT (source)-[:RATE]->(videos) return  videos.title, SUM(r.score) as score, COLLECT(users.name) as users order by score desc